# Unable to update couchbase document using POST REST API

Tags: rest, couchbase

I want to update a couchbase document with REST API

> ilceabcd1233.corp.abcd.com:8091/pools/default/buckets/{bucketName}/docs/{documentId}

When I hit below CURL command in postman, I receive 200 OK response Code with response as blank json Array: []

CURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'ilceabcd1233.corp.abcd.com:8091/pools/default/buckets/{bucketName}/docs/{documentId}' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yff' \
--data-raw '{"name": "Nisarg", "age": 50}'
```

When I retrieve this document by below CURL:

```
curl --location --request GET 'ilceabcd1233.corp.abcd.com:8091/pools/default/buckets/{bucketName}/docs/{documentId}' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yff'
```

it responds:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "id": "112176152456",
        "rev": "4-1637ac65ed7900000000000002000006",
        "att_reason": "invalid_json",
        "expiration": 0,
        "flags": 33554438
    },
    "base64": "",
    "xattrs": {}
}
```

On Couchbase web console I see message:

> "Binary document. Base64 not available"

Can any one please help, what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: FYI, updating documents through the REST API is not supported. That API basically exists for the Couchbase UI to use. This is why it's not in the documentation. I'm not saying *don't* use it, but proceed with caution. It could change or go away in future releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that this API doesn't actually accept JSON. It's looking for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Otherwise it will assume you are storing a binary document. You actually need a form `value`, which itself contains JSON. For example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/demo/docs/doc1' \
--header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwYXNzd29yZA==' \
--data-urlencode 'value={"foo": "bar"}'
```

And just to echo my comment, this is an undocumented, unsupported endpoint that's really meant for internal use only. It's recommended instead to use an SDK (like [the Couchbase Java SDK](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html), for instance) to read/write documents. The REST API is intended for Cluster management, not for CRUD.

Comment: You made my day man ! Great help :)

Thanks a lot @Matthew !!! :)